# Using web3.js, how can I get a TX hash before sending?

Tags: web3js

I'm using web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction() to obtain a rawTransaction, but I also need the transaction hash. calling web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction() will give me the hash, but I need to get it BEFORE sending the transaction. I tried using web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage(rawTransaction) but the result wasn't correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction( txObject, privateKey )
const txHash = await web3.utils.sha3(signed.rawTransaction);
console.log("TxHash Before send: "+txHash)
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction( signed.rawTransaction ).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
    console.log("TxHash from Receipt: ", receipt.transactionHash )
  })
```

```
TxHash Before send: 0x668f0a3fbd96a407f1821e7fb54346b808a3c9137b62f022a5b9061fa8732e18
TxHash from Receipt:  0x668f0a3fbd96a407f1821e7fb54346b808a3c9137b62f022a5b9061fa8732e18
```